# How can I add a symbol like $(SRCROOT) to use in an Xcode project's Build Settings?

Tags: xcode

The symbol $(SRCROOT) is useful when defining paths to files relative to your project's root folder. I want to define my own symbol for similar use in Build Settings.

For example, I would like to define `ENGINEROOT=~\don\engine`. Then, in Header Search Paths put `$(ENGINEROOT)\include`. This should resolve to `~\don\engine\include`.

I am using Xcode Version 8.0.

Comment: Put it in a .xcconfig file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a User-Defined value for this. This is in the Build Settings on the very bottom. To add, just click on the + button on the right in the screenshot below (below Capabilities).

[image]

You can then use it just like one of the built in environment variables. Note you can also change that value based on Configuration as well as Architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me: Xcode, iOS, Cordova and Ionic

1 - in Xcode change value of `$(SRCROOT)` for you root project
    in Xcode last variable of config build in user-defined
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12WrO.png)

2 - changed var. Clic the plus of up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRxge.png)

Note: root project is the location of my project and location where I use the pod.